# How to add more space for Postgresql Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, postgresql

I have just one, for example, `3TB` `HDD` - `/dev/sda1`

Here I store my `Postgresql` data - `/var/db/data`. How do I deal with the lack of disk space. Let's say the database stores about `2TB` of data. And `1TB` for everything else. Memory is running out. I connect another `HDD`. I mount it to folder. How do I associate a new disk space with `Postgres`? What can I use for this? Can there be some tools in the `Postgres` for such problems?

Thanks in advance)

**P.S**. Changing the data storage folder in the `Postgres` each time and dragging existing data into it every time is a bad idea as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL [tablespaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) when data must grow across several disks or disk partitions. From the documentation:

> By using tablespaces, an administrator can control the disk layout of
>   a PostgreSQL installation. This is useful in at least two ways. First,
>   if the partition or volume on which the cluster was initialized runs
>   out of space and cannot be extended, a tablespace can be created on a
>   different partition and used until the system can be reconfigured.
>
> Second, tablespaces allow an administrator to use knowledge of the usage pattern of database objects to optimize performance.

Comment: thank you) really helped